# How to make a response render nothing nor redirecting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, httpresponse

I have made a request using which developers can verify customer request. I want that when someone go one that request it just change the verification status in database and web page remains same just button get disabled like an ajax call but without ajax. I am using node and mongodb for back end and ejs for rendering. Is that even possible or I have to use user side ajax calls.

```
router.get('/verifycustomer/:id', redirectHome, async (req, res) => {
try{
    const id = req.params.id
    if(!id){
        req.flash('error_msg', 'Please provide a vlalid id of customer')
        return res.redirect('')
    }

    const customer = await Customer.updateOne({_id:id}, {verificationStatus:true})
    if(customer.nModified){
        req.flash('error_msg', 'Failed to verify customer Pleas try again.')
        return res.redirect('')
    }
    
    res.end()
} catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
    res.render('pages/505Error')
}
```

})

but but I end up with

[even if I use res.end or not it shows same result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBGJ9.png)

Comment: What if you render the same page but passing parameters as well? Something like `res.render("viewname", { status: "your-status" });`, and then retrieve the value you passed inside the view? It may help you.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you shouldn't use the `get` verb to update your database. That's a security risk. See [HTTP verbs and CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#HTTP_verbs_and_CSRF).